# Sharepoint Database Connection

Tags: sharepoint-2007

HI

We run Sharepoint 2007 1 Admin server, 1 Search Server, 2 Web servers and 1 database server.

I have noticed that at any one time there is always at least 80 connections to the sharepoint databases even when knowone is activly on site sites.

Is this normal?
What are the connections doing at activity monitor is showing the connections as sleeping?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint operates with a load of timer jobs running in the background to perform site administration tasks.  Take a look through the activity list in the admin site and you'll see all the things that are happening. I'd imagine these would account for a good number of the connections that you see listed.

Comment: Is there a reason why the search service holds onto 5 or 6 connections at any one time.

Comment: Depends how you have it set up - the service has a number of parts anyway doing different tasks. E.g. you can set it up to more than 1 crawl agent...  Entirely depends on your config but the search service has a whole is a pretty complex architecture so it's broken down it to a range of separate discrete processes that will will run independently.